# What are the rules or guidelines for recommending other non-SE forums?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, policy, etiquette

I suspect that [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/61233/consumer-rights-2015-u-k-faulty-vehicle-trader-avoids-responsibility) may be closed as it appears to be asking for specific legal advice, but I am aware of an English law forum that may assist.

Is it within SE rules, or the spirit, to send contributors elsewhere or is it seen as bad form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it within SE rules, or the spirit, to send contributors elsewhere or is it seen as bad form?

It is within SE rules. The notion of [referencing](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) is not limited to content posted on SE.

Directing users to other sources where they can get further information is valid, useful, and done very frequently. It makes no difference whether the external source is an online forum, a nonprofit or governmental agency that assists in that type of issues, an Amazon or Youtube link, or other materials on which the answer or comment is premised.